# Setup Bluetooth on a pi zero w

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero-w

i want to connect my bluetooth headset (not headset the smaller ones for mobiles) to my headless Pi zero w. But I can`t connect it, because it tells me there is no controller available and I want to know ho to fix it.

My commands were:

```
bluetoothctl
```

it returns:
   `[bluetooth]# nnect to bluetoothd...` Then after a while I type:`[bluetooth]# agent on`
   and get: `Agent registration enabled` back. After that I trys: `[bluetooth]# default-agent` and get this: `No agent is registered` and at least if I try: `[bluetooth]# scan on` I get this return: `No default controller available`.

`Sep 20 16:17:29 newscube systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Sep 20 16:17:29 newscube bluetoothd[370]: Bluetooth daemon 5.43
Sep 20 16:17:29 newscube systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Sep 20 16:17:29 newscube bluetoothd[370]: Starting SDP server
Sep 20 16:17:29 newscube bluetoothd[370]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Sep 20 16:17:29 newscube bluetoothd[370]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Sep 20 16:17:29 newscube bluetoothd[370]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Sep 20 16:17:29 newscube bluetoothd[370]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)`

Comment: Is the headset a HSP (Hand set) bluetooth profile ? Then you should be able to follow this instruction: https://scribles.net/enabling-hands-free-profile-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian-stretch-by-using-pulseaudio/

Comment: I give it a try

Comment: Please report back.

Comment: @MatsK My headset is the SoundBouds Sport IE20 from Anker, maybe thats helpfull.

Comment: @MatsK my problem is i don`t have a bluetooth dongle...

Comment: On a Pi Zero you should be able to use the internal one.

Comment: @MatsK nope it doesn`t work because it says no default controller available

Comment: OK I will test it tomorrow when I can setup the same scenario.

Comment: @MatsK ok nice maybe I do something wrong, maybe I try to rewrite the image on the sd card at Friday.

Comment: @MatsK I guess there is something wrong with this bluetoothd but I dont know how to remove the package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm having the same problem, and it seems like there's something off (or at least for me unexpected) with rights - I'm using a custom user, not `pi`, who is just member of its own group and sudoers.

To get `bluetoothctl` to work, I have to call it with elevated privilege, i.e. `sudo`.

Don't know if this a bug or a feature...

Comment: well, shame on me too, then - I tried out `bluetoothctl` on my laptop first, which runs ubuntu, and there I didn't need to use sudo... wrong expectations / assumptions?
I would love to hear if anybody could explain what the rights situation here is... Should that be its own question? : )

Comment: I guess it should be it`s own question. And another question can you check out my other bluetooth question ? Link https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/73659/bluetooth-disconnect . That would be nice maybe you know this answer too.

Comment: A custom user is likely absent in `bluetooth` and `audio` groups, that would explain why `sudo` helps. So it's a feature.

Answer (score 3):

Just try to add yourself to the bluetooth group using

`sudo usermod -aG bluetooth your_username`

and enjoy ... Do not forget the group is not propagated to the shell you are using at the moment. Reboot may be the safest thing?

Comment: reboot is not needed, just close the shell and open a new