# Bluetooth disconnect

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero-w

[image: New error]

I solved my previous Bluetooth issue, but now my problem is that every time I try to connect something (per Bluetooth) with the Pi Zero W it disconnects very quickly.

If I try to connect it to my PC, everything is fine, but I tried one headset, one mini headset (the stuff for running around outside) and a box and every time it says `connected: yes` and one moment later `connected: no`.

So what can I do? (If I run it with GUI it's working perfect but headless and with bluetoothctl it doesn't work).

Comment: You net to add logs and more facts about your problem.

Comment: @MatsK and were do i get them from? Is a screenshot enough?

Comment: @MatsK here it is everything except "TJ" isn`t working and thats a pc..

Comment: Noop, check `/var/log/messages` for errors when the connection/disconnection happened.

Comment: @MatsK I /var/log/messages isn´t something the latest time for today is 8:28:31. But i got lots of that`[CHG] Device 88:C6:26:8C:0B:82 UUIDs: 0000fe61-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 88:C6:26:8C:0B:82 ManufacturerData Key: 0x0003
`

Comment: @MatsK found something interesting here i change the image then you can see it.

Comment: What version pulseaudio are you using? I’ve had a horrible time with pa5. I’ve been suggesting using pa6 for a while and it has solved all my current Bluetooth issues.

Comment: @BrettReinhard I got version 10, with that I get no errors but no sound aswell. (second question: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/75700/raspberry-pi-zero-w-headless-bluetooth-audio-setup-problem)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience: I was trying to play sound over bluetooth with a raspberry pi zero w, on rasbian lite (headless) stretch.

Having read that you should use `pulseaudio`, since "the bluetooth stack" aka `bluez` doesn't support `ALSA` anymore, I saw that the above error message (protocol not available) disappeared whenever I had pulseaudio running, with certain bluetooth modules loaded (`module-bluetooth-policy` and `module-bluetooth-discover`), and I was able to connect and maintain the connection as well as use the bluetooth device as an audio sink.

But I couldn't get pulseaudio to run properly when deploying it as a service, neither in system-mode nor in user-mode... finally I gave up, especially since I discovered a [project that brings back integration of bluetooth with alsa directly](https://github.com/Arkq/bluez-alsa), and which is available in the standard repositories as `bluealsa` (with `stretch`!).

So since I unfortunately can't comment, this half answer is saying: If you're using pulseaudio, make sure to start it manually with modules loaded. Otherwise I suggest using `bluealsa`. And as far as I understand, the error message is telling you that it doesn't know how to handle this `A2DP` thing, which should give you a clue - have something running that knows how to communicate with devices through the `A2DP` protocol...

Comment: Ok thx I will try it

Comment: Is this bluealsa working with other voice output that is not saved in a .wav(example) file? So if I got a script that create sound or something can you hear that too?

Comment: I've successfully played a wav [using the alsa player as described on bluez-alsa](https://github.com/Arkq/bluez-alsa#configuration--usage) (aplay), and mplayer using `mplayer -ao alsa:device=bluealsa $MP3FILE` after setting up `asound.conf` as also described under the above link.

Comment: And another question: During the second installation step I get this error `configure: error: Package requirements (bluez >= 5.0) were not met: No package 'bluez' found` But I got Bluez Version: 5.43-2+rpt1+deb9u1. Whats wrong do I need exactly Version 5.0? (Here I find out how to grab the version maybe that is wrong: https://askubuntu.com/questions/352283/check-bluez-version-on-ubuntu-12-04/366094 , second answer)

Comment: hmm, not sure, sounds like it should be fine O_o

are you installing `bluez-alsa`? I maybe should have mentioned that with the stretch version of debian, it's already part of the standard repos, under the name `bluealsa`.

Comment: also, I was looking for it earlier, these [alsa notes](http://www.sabi.co.uk/Notes/linuxSoundALSA.html#appl) describe how to configure different players to use alsa and an alsa device.

Comment: Yep that was it... I will figure out how to run this and then I will post the answer here Thx againe (I removed bluealsa because I guessed it wasn`t working anymore)

Comment: cool, do that, looking forward to your fix! : )

Comment: Another error if I want to play sound via a python Script seems like more then one error any idea how to fix that.

Comment: not without more details, @Flajt : D
maybe you could post it as another question, with logs and your script, so I (and others) could take a look?

Comment: Log is above , the first image

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry about that! First question: Do you run the script with elevated privileges, i.e. with sudo? If you run it automatically, do you get the same logs when running the script manually with sudo?

Comment: No problem, if I run it without sudo it returns no errors but I get no sound.

Comment: Okay, that sounds weird at first, but is maybe no surprise - without sudo, alsa probably doesn’t even start working, hence no errors. I’m just guessing here, unfortunately... have you checked out [this post about jack, rasbian jessie and texttospeech](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=136974)? It would definitely help if you provided a minimal working example of your script, for reproduction purposes.

Comment: Hi, it`s me againe, with your answer I could short the error (thanks for that) but I´ve got still something (see new Image above).  For my code I use pyttsx (hope you can read it) (example:                                                                                                                                engine = pyttsx.init()


for i in text_list:
    #time.sleep(0.1)
    i=str(i)
    engine.say(i)    )