# Raspberry Pi zero W (headless) bluetooth audio setup problem

Tags: audio, bluetooth, pi-zero-w

I want to run a Python3 script with a text to speach engine called pyttsx3 to read some text via bluetooth.Unfortunally it does´t work. 
So what I have done is this:
First I have setted up a new Raspbian Image (newest Version: Stretch)
Then I´ve installed all dependencies via `pip3 and apt-get` 
Then I tried to run `sudo bluetoothctl` and pair, trust and connect but I got an alsa error. That I have fixed with `sudo apt-get install bluealsa`. 
After Rebooting and restarting and paring usw. I tried to run my script with sudo. 
I get this error: [image]
So then I have read in a [forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=136974) how to fix it. 
Then after fixing that (without the jackd2 installation, that doesn´t work) I ran the script againe and this happend: [image]
So I have googled some time and thought to run it with pulseaudio.
So I ran `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooh`. 
After that I reboot the system removed my device and reconnected it, then I tried to run the script againe and get the same error, so after figuring out that I have to run `pulseaudio --start` I have done this run the script againe and get another error... . sudo pulseaudio -v and now I have seen more detailed information so I tried to connect my device againe and it works (the connection). 
After that I ran the script againe and no errors have showed up, yeay. 
But no sound, so I ran `sudo bluetoothctl`and I saw that the bluetooth device connected after I run that command and could see it. So I googled againe and found [that](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=87138&start=100). (the second last but one post with the link) I configure it as they wrote it there. 
And againe I ran it and no sound so I looked at the output form `sudo pulseaudio -v` and figured out that the pi tried to pipe the output to a output called `alsa_output.platform-soc_audio.analog-stereo` but there is no analog audio card on the Pi (or am I wrong).
 
So and after this I googled a lot and ask a [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/75700/raspberry-pi-zero-w-headless-bluetooth-audio-setup-problem) here aswell and now this one because I can´t figure it out what to do. Because sometimes it connects and you can see via `pactl list cards` (but this happends only 2 times and I don´t know why) and via `sudo pulseaudio -v` but still no sound.
So I would recommend you to check my older question (the comments are very important) too because they recommend something aswell and this I have tried too. (I created a bunch of testing Images). So I hope everthing important is here, if you still need something simply ask me. EDIT: I tried this [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/bluetooth-audio-raspberry-pi-3/) today (17.01) and it worked on my Pi 3, so maybe it`s possible to run it on the Pi Zero W too (in headless mode).

Comment: Are you trying to create a bluetooth speaker?

Comment: @arjun I want some Sound output generated by a Python script using pyttsx send through some Bluetooth Headset, Box or something Else. ( so you can hear it)

Comment: You can first try to setup your pi as a dedicated bluetooth transmitter. There are many tutorials which cover that.- https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/bluetooth-audio-raspberry-pi-3/

Comment: @arjun is it working for pi zero w aswell?

Comment: why dont you try it.

Comment: @arjun I try it but I get a `Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed` error and it's for grafical usage and I want it headless. So maybe it`s working but with this error I can't go on. Any idea how to fix ? (Install bluz-alsa with pulseaudio support from github?)

Comment: First with your device connected, use pactl to list cards, pactl list cards, find your devices card number, then set the card profile to a2dp_sink, pactl set-card-profile $CardNumber a2dp_sink . From there you should get some output to the device. Given you have audio running to that sinks

Comment: @Brett Reinhard ok I will try Wednesday (is it correct?) and report  what I will get.

Comment: @Flajt if it connects but you can’t hear audio, the above comment I made will likely fix it.

Comment: I should have asked this earlier but I saw you talk about bluezalsa are you using stretch or raspbian jessie?

Comment: @Brett Reinhard I guess it was stretch

Comment: @BrettReinhard He only find card 0 called alsa_card.platform-soc_audio,

Comment: For bluezalsa checkout the comment made by ken b here: https://bitbucket.org/togiles/lightshowpi/pull-requests/124/enabled-bluetooth-speaker-headphone/diff . He got it working with bluezalsa on stretch

Comment: @BrettReinhard Maybe I am to dump for this but it still doesn`t work....

Comment: @BrettReinhard Ignore pls the above. I have done everthing like the tutorial but still nothing... . But I think the Pi is killing the connection you can hear normally a little whisper when you are connected but there is no sound. I can hear that for some seconds but then it disappears. And if I type in sudo bluetoothd it isn't connected or it reconnects fast, but there should be no loading time for displaying or? Any Idea what to do...?

Comment: @BrettReinhard I found my Card but if I try to run the second command it returns `You have to specify a card name/index and a profile name` but I enter my Card number (5) and I can`t hear something.

Comment: @BrettReinhard I figured out that it disconnects my bluetooth device. I got that fixed but now I can´t hear something with it and I can´t display it with pactl list cards. Any idea what to do? Beacuase it create a stream with pulseaudio but I only hear the wisper of an active bluetooth device.

Comment: @BrettReinhard I got it connected as audio card with raspbian jessie, but I can`t hear something too. So I guess there is a pulseaudio problem because in the log you can see that it trys to force the sound not to the bluez bluetooth device (but that it tried in raspbian stretch) and it return some bluez4 error while starting the pulseaudio -v command. If you need I upload log files and how you can set a comment as a answer comment to close questions? (Sorry for this commentary spam attack)

Comment: The comments section is not for extended discussions. Any new information should be added as an edit to the question.

Comment: @Darth Vader I created a new question for that problem.

Comment: I was trying to make this work recently and spent days trying to figure it out.  There is a huge number of similar issues.  I remember coming across posts saying there are issues with the wireless Broadcom chipset in the PiZeroW that make it not work as an audio sink.  It will require the foundation to fix it. I apologize for not having links.  I will post them here as soon as I rediscover them

Comment: @Inflexionist Ok thanks so much, (I am sitting here for months without something working well...) Do you think it can be solved with an externel Bluetooth dongle/adapter?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the work around.  For the record, all the issues with BT seem to be around using BT speakers and headsets.  Other devices like keyboards seem to work as far as I can tell.